# Hibernate StatelessSession, "the statement is closed" exception

Tags: java, hibernate, session, seam

Hi I am using `StatelessSession` Interface for bulk inserts and I got an exception: "The statement is closed".

Below are details I was using in my code, I got through google with this exception and did not found a solution.

**Sample Code:**

```
    @Name("sample")
    @Scope(ScopeType.STATELESS)
    @AutoCreate
    public Sample{  

        @In
        private SessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory;

        @Begin(join=tru)
        public void migrate(){
            StatelessSession session = hibernateSessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            for(DoTempCustomers tempCust:doTempCustomers){
                  TempCustomers temp=new TempCustomers();
                  BeanUtils.copyProperties(temp, tempCust);
                  session.insert(temp);
            }       
        }

        tx.commit();
        session.close();
     }
  }
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">java:/mobeeSessionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">mobeeadminDataSource</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</property>

<!-- Here are the mappings -->
<mapping package="com.manam.mobee.persist.entity"/>
<mapping class="com.manam.mobee.persist.entity.TempCustomers"/>
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The statement is closed.
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedStatement.checkState(WrappedStatement.java:599)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setString(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:313)
        at org.hibernate.type.StringType.set(StringType.java:26)
        at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1997)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2243)
        ... 96 more
12:16:54,777 INFO  [STDOUT] [Mobee]- INFO 2012-12-08 12:16:54,777 [] StringType - could not bind value 'TIMOTHY NDUNG'U MAINA' to parameter: 1; The statement is closed.
12:16:54,777 INFO  [STDOUT] [Mobee]- WARN 2012-12-08 12:16:54,777 [] JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
12:16:54,777 INFO  [STDOUT] [Mobee]-ERROR 2012-12-08 12:16:54,777 [] JDBCExceptionReporter - The statement is closed.
12:16:54,778 ERROR [STDERR] org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.manam.mobee.persist.entity.TempCustomers]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntity
```

Can you please tell me how to solve this exception?

Comment: After proper indent of your code, this doesn't look correct, can you correct the code?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with IBM DB2 database, while migrating Hibernate from 3.4 to 5.4.x version.

after googling and looking at various forums, issue is with the version of DB2 driver. following thread has more details on the issue.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/why-does-isclosed-throw-exception-when-used-resultset

I updated DB2 driver which has support for JAVA8, it fixed issue.